# Pushing elements to a vector within a ranged based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Could someone explain to me why this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for(auto i: v)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(auto i: v)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
        v.push_back(4);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(auto i: v)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Code posted here: http://cpp.sh/5kxdu

Outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 0 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

While I would expect:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

I know it's bad to modify the vector during the `for` loop (was just trying something else when I hit this). After `v` declaration, `v.capacity()` returns `6` and obviously, adding `v.reserve(12)` after `v` is declared fixes the issue. There is definitely something related to the vector reallocating itself to expand its capacity during the `push_back` operation.

But I'm wondering if that's just an undetermined behaviour and I was just lucky that only the second element was wrong or if this is something predictable and explainable (considering how the `for` loop works).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) has the form of

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
         __end = end_expr; 
         __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

and sets the `begin` and `end` iterators at the start of the loop.  When you call `push_back` it always invalidates the `end` iterator and if `size` grows larger than the `capacity` then all iterators are invalidated.

So using `push_back` is going to cause undefined behavior as you are using iterators that are no longer valid.

Comment: So the output could have been much more messed up than it was, right?

Comment: @jpo38 Yes.  Since it has UB it could have cause daemons to fly out of the computer.

Answer (score 2):

After the first `push_back` the vector reallocates its buffer and iterators in the ranged for loop are invalidated.

Comment: I would say it may reallocate buffers.

Comment: @Slava Since the OP says the capacity is 6 it is guaranteed that it will reallocate.

Comment: @NathanOliver yea missed that part in question, I am very sloppy today :(

Comment: @Slava `for( Slava ) give("Coffe");`

Comment: @Slava IMHO either the vector reallocate its buffer or it allocates a new one . Plural (i.e., buffers) I think it would be misleading, since a vector has one buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the iterator used by the for loop can be invalidated during the push back. Under the hood the vector uses a buffer, and the push_back can cause the array to be reallocated.

More references here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5189/

[What happens under the hood of vector::push_back memory wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899973/what-happens-under-the-hood-of-vectorpush-back-memory-wise)