# c++ tokenize std string

Tags: c++, tokenize, strtok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Hello I was wondering how I would tokenize a std string with strtok

```
string line = "hello, world, bye";    
char * pch = strtok(line.c_str(),",");
```

I get the following error

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
error: initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strtok(char*, const char*)’
```

I'm looking for a quick and easy approach to this as I don't think it requires much time

Comment: I have seen this kind of questions before. Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I always use `getline` for such tasks.

```
istringstream is(line);
string part;
while (getline(is, part, ','))
  cout << part << endl;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
std::string::size_type pos = line.find_first_of(',');
std::string token = line.substr(0, pos);
```

to find the next token, repeat `find_first_of` but start at `pos + 1`.

Comment: With this, there would have to be another variable to keep track of pos1 and pos2. Otherwise, you would be using substring from 0 to what the new pos is, instead of pos1 to pos2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strtok` by doing `&*line.begin()` to get a non-const pointer to the `char` buffer. I usually prefer to use [`boost::algorithm::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3240174) though in C++.

Comment: I think by discarding the const on the internal pointer of the string, you allow strtok to modify the string's internal pointer - very dirty.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  It will put the `std::string` into an undefined state.  You are not supposed to modify a `std::string` using C string functions.

Comment: @japreiss How can it possibly go wrong? There's nothing wrong with modifying the characters in a string through its iterators, and C++ strings are [always contiguous in practice](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530), and are guaranteed to be contiguous and null-terminated in C++11.

Comment: @spencercw: There is no guarantee that the string's internal representation is zero-terminated; and it might use copy-on-write semantics, in which case subverting `const` could change other copies of the string. It might (or might not) be possible to demonstrate that what you're doing is well-defined for any conformant implementation, but even if you can, I wouldn't like to test the edge cases of conformance like that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The internal buffer is guaranteed to be null-terminated in C++11 ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7554172/766580)). You raise an interesting point with copy-on-write though. I would guess that in such an implementation dereferencing the iterator would trigger the copy, or some sort of memory guard would trigger the copy anyway when `strtok` writes to the buffer. Are there any implementations that actually do CoW?

Comment: @spencercw: No, C++11 doesn't guarantee that the buffer is zero-terminated; just that the characters of the string are stored contiguously, `s[s.size()] == 0`, and `s.data()` and `s.c_str()` return `const` pointers to zero-terminated arrays. In practice that means that any sane implementation will use a zero-terminated contiguous buffer, but it's not guaranteed. GCC uses CoW; they've probably got all the awkward details of access via pointer-to-dereferenced-iterator right, but personally I'd rather not rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is a rather quirky, evil function that modifies its argument. This means that you can't use it directly on the contents of a `std::string`, since there's no way to get a pointer to a mutable, zero-terminated character array from that class.

You could work on a copy of the string's data:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(line.c_str(), line.c_str()+line.size()+1);
char * pch = strtok(&buffer[0], ",");
```

or, for more of a C++ idiom, you could use a string-stream:

```
std::stringstream ss(line);
std::string token;
std::readline(ss, token, ',');
```

or find the comma more directly:

```
std::string token(line, 0, line.find(','));
```

Comment: There is no std::readline(). Did you mean std::getline()?