# Is returned string null-terminated from getline()?

Tags: c++, string, getline

One thing I'm not pretty sure after googling for a while, is the returned string of getline(). Hope to get it confirmed here.

```
std::getline
```

This global version returns a **std::string** so it's not necessarily null-terminated. Some compilers may append a '\0' while the others won't.

```
std::istream::getline
```

This function returns a **c-style string** so it's guaranteed that the string is null-terminated.

Is that right?

Comment: null terminated doesn't mean anything for `std::string`. A string object stores the length and the pointer to the first byte of the string, and that is it. What you are guaranteed however is that when you call c_str, you get a null terminated array of characters.

Comment: C++11 guarantees the internal representation of `std::string`'s data is null-terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null termination is a concept that is applicable only to C strings; it does not apply to objects of `std::string` - they let you find the size by calling `size()`, and do not require null termination. However, strings returned from `std::string`'s `c_str()` function are null terminated, regardless of where the data for the string came from.

C++11 standard describes the prerequisites of the `operator [pos]` in the section 21.4.5.2:

> Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undeﬁned behavior.

Note the `pos < size()`, as opposed to `pos <= size()`: the standard explicitly allows `std::string` objects not to have null termination.

Comment: Does C++11 enforce that internal data of std::string is null-terminated, like GMan said?

Comment: @EricZ Only as far as you can tell using the externally visible APIs: specifically, it guarantees that `data()` and `c_str()` will return a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of characters. There, in section 21.4.7.1.1 it says that the valid range for elements returned by `data()` and `c_str()` is `[0..size()]`, inclusive, implying that the sequence is null-terminated.

Comment: @EricZ: If you take `&str[0]`, you get a null-terminated buffer. It's implied by other clauses, and is an intentional change in C++11.

Comment: @GManNickG Very interesting... I don't have the official standard, only the latest draft. It sounds like there's an inconsistency among different places in the standard when it comes to element at `[size()]`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7554172/87234) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077274/87234).

Comment: @GManNickG This is very interesting - your #1 link quotes from the same section 21.4.5.2, but it has a `<=` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 0):

> The ending null character that signals the end of a c-string is automatically appended to s after the data extracted.