# Getting char * or const char * data from a string breaks for 16 character strings or longer

Tags: c++, string, char, c-str

I have a function `string_to_char()` which attempts to give me a form of a string which I can pass into a library I am using, which wants `char *` (but I think works with `const char *`, so I've been trying both).

The code I wrote to test my implementation of `string_to_char()` goes as such:

```
#include <iostream>

const std::string endl = "\n";

char * string_to_char(std::string str)
{
    return (char*) str.c_str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string test1 = "Some test strin";
    std::string test2 = "Some test string";

    char * result1 = string_to_char(test1);
    char * result2 = string_to_char(test2);

    std::cout << "part1" << endl;
    std::cout << result1 << endl;
    std::cout << string_to_char(test1) << endl;

    std::cout << "part2" << endl;
    std::cout << result2 << endl;
    std::cout << string_to_char(test2) << endl;

    std::cout << "done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
part1
Some test strin
Some test strin
part2

Some test string
done
```

So for some reason, `string_to_char()` only properly works with strings with 15 characters or shorter, and outputs from the function straight to std::cout, but can't seem to store it to a variable for 16 characters or longer.

I am relatively new to C++ so some of the code below may seem a bit strange to more experienced programmers, but here is the code that I have tried in place of `return (char*) str.c_str();`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

char * string_to_char(std::string str)
{
    return (char*) str.c_str();
    
    return const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
    
    std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
    char * chr;
    vec.push_back('\0');
    chr = (char*) &vec[0];
    //chr = & (*vec.begin());
    return chr; //all outputs from both are empty with this both versions of chr
    
    return &str[0]; //this makes the output from the 15 character string also be empty when put in a
    //variable, but the function going directly to std::cout is fine

    return strcpy((char *) malloc(str.length() + 1), str.c_str()); //this one works with everything, but 
    //it looks like it leaks memory without further changes

    std::vector<char> copied(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);
    return copied.data(); //returns "random" characters/undefined behaviour for both outputs in test1 and is empty for both
    //outputs in test2
}
```

Using `const` instead, and changing `char * result1 = string_to_char(test1);` to `const char * result1 = string_to_char(test1);` (as with `result2`), to see if that works with these other solutions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

const char * string_to_char(std::string str)
{
    return (char*) str.c_str();

    return str.c_str();

    return (const char*) str.c_str();

    return str.data();

    return const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()); 

    std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
    char * chr;
    vec.push_back('\0');
    chr = (char*) &vec[0];
    //chr = & (*vec.begin());
    return chr; //completely breaks both

    return &str[0]; //both appear empty when given to a variable, but works fine when taken straight to std::cout
 
    return strcpy((char *) malloc(str.length() + 1), str.c_str()); //memory leak, as when not using const

    std::vector<char> copied(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);
    return copied.data(); //same as when not using const
}
```

I got a lot of the given methods from:

[std::string to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char)

[string.c_str() is const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916787/string-c-str-is-const)

[How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

[Converting from std::string to char * in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026580/converting-from-stdstring-to-char-in-c)

With a bit of reading around the topic for strings and vectors at https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: The fact that you have to explicitly cast something to `char *` should be a honking clue that something is wrong. An isolated cast is never a valid solution, by itself, to a compilation error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `const_cast`ing c_str() from non-const string is OK, and this is not the cause of OP's issues.

Comment: Honestly, I can't believe handling a `std::string`, `char *`, and `const char *` takes 2 or 3 screens-worth of code.  It looks [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)-ish.

Answer (score 5):

The pointer returned from `c_str()` is only valid as long as the string is alive. You get [expected output](https://godbolt.org/z/6WqMvhe18) when you pass a reference:

```
auto string_to_char(std::string& str)
{
    return str.c_str();
}
```

Because now the pointer returned is into the buffer of the string of the caller. In your code the caller gets a pointer to the functions local string (because you pass a copy).

Though, instead of calling the function you can directly call `c_str()`. That also mitigates the problem of holding on to the pointer after the string is gone to some extend.

Comment: One can also avoid casting by calling `std::string::data`.

Comment: In the current form, the function is devoid of any purpose. Rescinding my upvote.

Comment: @SergeyA it had not purpose in first place. OP needs either a `char*` or a `const char*`, both are fine. I am also suggesting not to use the function

Comment: Original version did improve's OP's code, as it incorporated `const_cast` (assuming OP needed non-const pointer). This version is simply returning result of `c_str` unchanged, and can be dropped-replaced by call to `c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

You've overthought this. There is no need two write this function yourself. [`std::string::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) already exists and returns a pointer to the string's null-terminated internal buffer. Assuming you're using C++17 or later, this pointer will be `const char*` if the `std::string` object is `const`-qualified (i.e. read-only), and otherwise will be a modifiable `char*`.

```
std::string test1 = "string";
const std::string test2 = "const string";

char* result1 = test1.data();
const char* result2 = test2.data();
```

This pointer is valid for as long as the `std::string` object that it came from is alive and is not modified (except for modifying individual elements).

Also note that casting pointers and casting away `const`-ness is a very easy way to cause Undefined Behaviour without knowing it. You should avoid C-style casts in general (e.g. `(char*)str.c_str()`) because they're very unsafe. See [this Q/A on the proper use of C++ casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) for more information.

[Live Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2615220c5513be27)

[Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: Note that `string::data()` does not return a non-const pointer until C++17, so a cast would be needed in earlier versions. Otherwise, you would have to use `&str[0]` instead, which is only guaranteed to work in C++11 and later (but likely will work in practice in all widely-used implementations).

Answer (score 1):

`string_to_char()` is taking its `str` parameter by value, so a *copy* of the caller's input string is made.  When the function exits, that copied `std::string` will be destroyed. Thus, the returned `char*` pointer will be left dangling, pointing to freed memory, and any use of that pointer to access the data will be **undefined behavior**.

Pass in the `str` parameter by reference instead:

```cpp
char* string_to_char(std::string &str)
{
    return const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
}
```

Or, in C++17 and later, you can use this instead:

```cpp
char* string_to_char(std::string &str)
{
    return str.data();
}
```

Which then begs the question of why you need `string_to_char()` at all and don't just use `data()` directly, unless you are not using a modern version of C++.

Comment: Well, that would be wrong. While `const_cast`ing result of `c_str` for non-const `std::string` is OK (it is guaranteed to return the same thing as `data`, which returns non-const pointer), doing the same for `const`-qualified `std::string` is evil.

Comment: @drescherjm Not the down voter but this answer is a potential source of UB.  It takes a `const string&`, so there is no way to know if the `const_cast` in it is actually legal.

Comment: It's also really easy to cause an UB with something like `string_to_char("foo")`.