# Null termination in strings

Tags: java, c++, c, string

Yes, I did check other threads and I have come to a conclusion. **I just want you to confirm it so that I don't have any misconceptions.**

> Java String objects are not null terminated.
>
> C++ std::string objects are also not null terminated
>
> C strings or C-style strings if you will (array of characters), are the only strings that are null-terminated.

Correct or Incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

C-strings are 0-terminated strings. You aren't forced to use them in C though.

Both C++ `std::string` and Java strings are counted strings, which means they store their length.

[But C++ `std::string`s are *also followed by a 0 since C++11*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11), making them 0-terminated if (as often the case) they don't contain any embeddded 0, for better interoperability with 0-terminated-string APIs.

Comment: @iwolf: Actually, it could not. At least since C++11.

Comment: @rici: I'll suffer it anyway. Also, made it maddeningly correct.

Answer (score 2):

All of those are in themselves correct, but petty pedantery: C-style strings are not unique to C, there are other places where such things occur (most commonly in various forms of Assembler code, and C being a language originally designed to be "slightly above assembler" makes this "no surprise").

And in C++11, `std::string` is guaranteed to have a NUL terminator after the last actual string character [but it's valid to store NULL characters inside the string if you wish] (at least if you call `c_str()`, but in the implementations I've looked at, it's stored there on creation/update)

Answer (score 1):

All the statements are not wrong, but need to clarify more of the specifics in each of the mentioned languages.

Comment: Thank you. That means a lot coming from you.

Comment: Actually, they aren't.

Comment: All the statements are too vague.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why buddy?

Comment: @Grendan: Just see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct c++ `std::string` and java `String` both hold private fields indicating the length of the string. A NULL terminator is not needed.

The `std::string` method `c_str` returns the string as a NULL terminated char array for use when a NULL terminator is required e.g. c string functions such as `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct.

- C-string are not just an array of characters. They are a *null-terminated* array of characters.

  So if you have an array of characters, it's not a C-string yet, it's just an ordinary array of characters. It has to have a terminating null character to be a valid C-style string.
- Additionally, an `std::string` [**must** also be null-terminated (since C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554172/3425536). (But it still has a private variable holding the length of the string.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I love you.

Comment: @zenith: Since C++11, it *must* be 0-terminated.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh that's news to me. Thanks. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Java part, but in C++11 `std::string`s are NUL-terminated (besides storing the chars count), i.e. `&s[0]` returns the same string as `s.c_str()` (which is NUL-terminated, as a raw C-style string).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077274/1629821) for more details.

Comment: So, is the null termination character stored at index 0 instead of the last index in c++ 11? Can you please elaborate buddy? We're on to something very interesting here. :)

Comment: @Grendan: Seems like trying to include the reasoning there.

Comment: @Grendan: &s[0] is a pointer to the beginning of the string wrapped in the std::string class. If this pointer points to the same string returned by c_str(), since c_str() returns a NUL-terminated string by definition (i.e. a NUL-terminated C-style string), then this implies that also the string returned by &s[0] is NUL-terminated. The NUL-terminator is at the END of the string. Note also that since std::strings keep the character count, you can also have more than one single NUL char embedded in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to be asking is why C-String should be null terminated.

The answer is the string manipulation functions needs to know the exact length of the string. As strings in C are just array of characters there is no information that tells (this is the size of this array) they need something to help determining the size of array which is the null character standing at the end of it.

Where as in Java strings are instances of the `String` class which has the `length` field so there is no need for the null termination.

The same thing apply to strings in c++.