# Misuse of GL info log null terminating character in std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, shader, stdstring

I have a fairly simple `log()` method for a GL shader and program convenience classes, since the respective `compile` and `link` methods only return a `bool`, while hiding all the GL calls; e.g.,

```
std::string
glShader::log () const
{
    std::string info;
    GLint len = 0;

    if (!glIsShader(gl_shader_obj))
        info = "(invalid shader object)\n";
    else
        glGetShaderiv(gl_shader_obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, & len);

    if (len != 0)
    {
        info.resize(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(len));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(gl_shader_obj, len, NULL, & info[0]);
    }

    return info;
}
```

Is this a misuse of the `std::string::resize (size_type)` argument? I known that C++11 mandates a null terminating character when queried, i.e., `c_str()`; but does it guarantee its presence in the storage? This might be a 'reasonable' way to implement `string` to simplify C string access, but not a requirement.

However, `GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH` includes `\0` in the number of characters in the log, provided there is a log; otherwise the log length is simply zero.

Am I potentially writing past the end of the `string`'s reserved buffer in this fashion? Should I be using `(len - 1)` in the `InfoLog` call? Or do I have the idea about C++11 strings wrong? That is, can I safely overwrite with the null terminator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid use of `std::string`. You can get a pointer to the first character and write to the array of characters, so long as you don't exceed the range [0, `size()`).

However, you did make one mistake. See, `GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH` includes the NUL terminator character in the length. Which means that, technically speaking, your `std::string` is one character longer than it needs to be. The last character of `info` will be a NUL character, and the `std::string` will treat that like it is part of the string's data, rather than a delimiter marking the end of the string.

You should *not* try to fix this by subtracting 1 from `len` before setting `info`'s size. Why? Because `glGetShaderInfoLog` will *always* NUL terminate the string it writes. So if you shrink `len`, it will chop off the last actual character from the log.

Instead, you should shrink `info` after you've copied it from OpenGL:

```
info.resize(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(len));
glGetShaderInfoLog(gl_shader_obj, len, NULL, & info[0]);
info.pop_back();
```

---

In C++17, the standard wording has changed to allow writing to the NUL-terminator of a string, so long as you are overwriting it with a NUL character. It also allows `string::data` to return a non-`const` character array. Therefore, this will work fine now:

```
info.resize(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(len - 1));
glGetShaderInfoLog(gl_shader_obj, len, NULL, info.data());
```

The standard requires that `info` will have size+1 bytes in it.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that `InfoLog` NUL terminates regardless. So the `end()` iterator yields the 'real' `\0`, and the prefix `--` yields the position of my 'false' `\0` that I want to be rid of, right?

Comment: @BrettHale: No, `end()` returns an iterator one-past-the-end of the string. You are *not* allowed to assume that `string::end()` is dereferencable and that it will return the NUL character. To put it a different way, the fact that `std::string` is NUL terminated is a hidden detail. The code I wrote above is just snipping off the last character, which we know is a NUL character written by `glGetShaderInfoLog`. It has nothing to do with `string`'s own internal NUL terminator.

Comment: Of course. Forgetting iterator ranges are half-open... I'm tying myself in knots here. Also wondering if the `pop_back` method would be useful. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @NicolBolas: "To put it a different way, the fact that std::string is NUL terminated is a hidden detail." Is it actually though? I mean if `std::string` supports `c_str` in any reasonable way (that doesn't involve suddenly making a copy) then the NUL really must be there, no? I suppose its possible that `string::end` is not exactly what you might expect... I mean you definitely make your code less generic if not outright wrong if you ever treat an `end` iterator as dereferenceable.

Comment: I guess it was discussed at length [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554039/is-stringc-str-no-longer-null-terminated-in-c11) some years ago

Comment: @ChrisBeck: "*Is it actually though?*" Who cares? The standard clearly says that dereferencing the `end` iterator yields undefined behavior.