# glGetShaderInfoLog to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, opengl

This is a snippet from OpenGL Super Bible 7th edition:

```
GLint log_length;
glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
std::string str;
str.reserve(log_length);
glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, log_length, NULL, str.c_str());
```

At a first glance it seemed weird to me to pass `str.c_str()` as an argument to this function, and of course clang immediatelly protested: `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'GLchar *' (aka 'char *') with an rvalue of type 'const char *'`.

So I tried to investigate and changed `str.c_str()` to `str.data()`, which should provide a pointer to the internal data array, but this produces the same error message. **Edit:** `c_str()` and `data()` are actually the same thing (in c++11 at least), so it doesn't matter which one we use.

I did some searches, but didn't find a solution (although I'm quite new to C++ and some things are still not obvious to me).

Is this an error in the book? And is there a way to make it work with std::string?

Comment: @Asu actually, `c_str()` and `data()` are the same thing and they both return `const char*`. I also thought that `data()` returned `char*` without the `const`.

Comment: After some verification, `c_str()` always does return a `const char*` and since C++17 `data()` can return a `char*`. Sounds like you're going to need a C++17 compliant compiler that supports this yet or find an alternative.

Comment: I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203117/misuse-of-gl-info-log-null-terminating-character-in-stdstring) a related question a while back. `& str[0]` is the easy way to access the storage, but be careful of NUL termination and length assumptions.

Comment: Try `const_cast`?(NOTE: that can makes your code messy)
`const_cast<char*>(some_const_char_pointer)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `string::c_str()` and `string::data()` return a `const char*` until C++17. Since C++17, `string::data()` has an overload that will return a `char*`. This means this code snippet is invalid.

Edit: An easier and as efficient solution is to use `&str[0]`. The subscript operator will return a `char&`.

If you cannot use C++17, you could use a `std::vector<char>`, which does have a non-const `data()`, but this will cause a copy when constructing a `std::string`:

```
// ...
std::vector<char> v(log_length);
glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, log_length, NULL, v.data());
std::string s(begin(v), end(v));
```

Also, `reserve()` isn't sufficient, because the actual `size()` is not changed. If `c_str()` returned a `char*`, the snippet would actually also cause undefined behavior.

Comment: FYI: You could just use `&str[0]` to get a non-`const` pointer.

Comment: I don't believe