# Will C++11 std::string::operator[] return null-terminated buffer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an object of the `std::string` class that I need to pass to C function that operates the `char*` buffer by iterating over it and searching for the null terminated symbol.

So, I have something like this:

```
// C function
void foo(char* buf);

// C++ code
std::string str("str");
foo(&str[0]);
```

Suppose that we use C++11, so we have a guarantee that `std::string` representation will have contiguously stored characters.

But I wonder is there any guarantee that `&str[0]` will point to the buffer that ends with `\0`? Yeah, there's `c_str` member function but I'm talking about `operator[]`.

Can somebody quote the standard please?

Comment: Yes, but `str.data()`/ `str.c_str()` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Mohit Jain Because that function accepts `char*`, not `const char*`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554039/is-stringc-str-no-longer-null-terminated-in-c11

Comment: @FrozenHeart I am not 100% but I think that modifying the buffer of a `std::string` is probably UB (see the *Requires* in @Zereges answer).

Comment: @Holt But foo doesn't mofidy the existing buffer, it just iterates over it

Comment: @FrozenHeart Then why do you need a `char*` instead of a `const char*`?

Comment: @Holt Well, I can't modify that function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice, yes.  There are exactly zero implementations of `std::string` that are standards-comforming that do not store a NUL character at the end of the buffer.

So if you aren't wondering for wondering sake,  you are done.

However, if you are wondering about the standard being abtruse:

---

In C++14, yes.  There is a clear requirement that `[]` return a contiguous set of elements, and `[size()]` must return a NUL character, and const methods may not modify state.  So `*((&str[0])+size())` must be the same as `str[size()]`, and `str[size()]` must be a NUL, thus game over.

---

In C++11, almost certainly.  There are rules that `const` methods may not modify state.  There are guarantees that `data()` and `c_str()` return a null-terminated buffer that agrees with `[]` at each point.

A convoluted reading of C++11 standard would state that prior to any call of `data()` or `c_str()`, `[size()]` doesn't return the NUL terminator at the end of the buffer but rather a `static const CharT` that is stored separately, and the buffer has an unitialized (or even a trap value) where NUL should be.  Due to the requirement that `const` methods not modify state I believe this reading is incorrect.

This requires `&str[str.size()]` change between calls to `.data()`, which is an observable change in state in `string` over a `const` call, which I would read as being illegal.

An alternative way to get around the standard might be to not initialize `str[str.size()]` until you legally access it via calling `.data()`, `.c_str()` or actually passing `str.size()` to `operator[]`.  As there are no defined ways to access that element other than those 3 in the standard, you could stretch things and say lazy initialization of the NUL is legal.

I'd question this, as the definition of `.data()` implies that the return value of `[]` is contiguous, so `&[0]` is the same address as `.data()`, and `.data()+.size()` is guaranteed to point to a NUL `CharT` so must `(&[0])+.size()`, and with no non-`const` methods called the state of the `std::string` may not change between the calls.

But, what if the fact the compiler can look and see you'll never call `.data()` or `.c_str()`, does the requirement of contiguity hold if it can be proven you never call them?

At which point I'd throw my hands up and shoot the hostile compiler.

---

The standard is very passively voiced about this.  So there may be a way to make an arguably standards conforming `std::string` that doesn't follow these rules.  And because the guarantees get closer and closer to explicitly requiring that NUL terminator there, the odds against a new compiler showing up that uses a tortured reading of C++ to claim this is standards compliant is low.

Comment: I think this falls into Occam's Implementation: The simplest implementation is the most likely until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Mgetz True, but we also want to ensure that no pathological compiler comes along and says "that is UB, so I'll optimize around it not happening".  *cough* gcc *cough* something in my throat.

Comment: *At which point I'd throw my hands up and shoot the hostile compiler.* Also cremate it and scatter the ashes so it cannot bother anyone ever again.

Comment: "There is a clear requirement that [] return a contiguous set of elements, and [size()] must return a NUL character" -- could you quote it? In fact, I don't see any differences between `operator[]` descriptions in C++11 and C++14 drafts

Answer (score 5):

According to standard, yes. Underlying char container is accessible using `string::data` or `string::c_str` on which standard says:

> 21.4.7.1 `basic_string` accessors [**[string.accessors]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.accessors#1)
>   `const charT* c_str() const noexcept;`
>   `const charT* data() const noexcept;`
>
> 1 *Returns:* A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
>   2 *Complexity:* Constant time.
>   3 *Requires:* The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

And to prove, that it's null-terminated, look at definition of `operator[]` (emphasis mine):

> 21.4.5 `basic_string` element access [**[string.access]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.access#2)
>   `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
>   `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> 1 *Requires:* `pos <= size().`
>   2 *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. **Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.**
>   3 *Throws*: Nothing.
>   4 *Complexity*: Constant time.

thus `operator[size()]` returns `charT()` and since `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char>`, `charT()` is `'\0'`.

That means, in your case, `*(&str[0] + str.size()) == '\0'` shall be, according to standard, always `true`.

---

Beware, that modifying `operator[size()]` is UB.

Comment: Where does it state that it should be null-terminated?

Comment: Exactly. I was searching for this. I had read this long back.

Comment: Does point 3 mean that you *shouldn't* use this to pass that pointer to function accepting `char*`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Think logically and step by step: 1) `c_str()` has to be null-terminated (it is mentioned elsewhere in the spec) .... 2) and `p+i == &operator[](i)` is valid for all `i` in the range `[0, size()]` which means the address of last character when `i==size()` is `\0`.

Comment: @el.pescado exactly, if you need to pass a string that might be modified I suggest copying it (including the 0 terminator) to a vector 1st.

Comment: @el.pescado But `foo` doesn't mofidy the existing buffer, it just iterates over it

Comment: @FrozenHeart perhaps foo should be `void foo(char const * buf);` then

Comment: @Richard Critten Well, I can't modify that function

Comment: This describes the effect of calling `data()` and `c_str()`.  The OP asked about `(&str[0])+str.size()` which does not involve calling `data()` or `c_str()`.  A connection may be made, but it is not free.

Comment: @FrozenHeart by the way, do you want "practically"?  Practically this is absolutely safe, there are no compliant `std::string` implementations without the property you ask for.  What is going on is the fact that the standard is *extremely abtruse* in this section about it.

Comment: @Nawaz I said it wasn't free, not that it cannot be made.